# Integrating payment services (PayPal & Stripe) into Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, paypal, stripe-payments

I've managed to create payment links through ***PayPal button*** and a wordpress website plugin ***Stripe Payments*** for my chrome extension.

And I've added those payment links in my chrome extension.
[image: Integrated Links]

[image: Stripe Payment]

The problem I'm facing is to verify if the payment has been paid successfully. And depending on the payment, I would upgrade the user's plan to Pro version. I've tried exploring PayPal and Stripe APIs. But they didn't help much.
Also to store the information of paid users, I was thinking of using chrome local storage which can be synced across the devices. Is there any other better way to do it on the client side?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: For Stripe, you'd want to use webhooks for purchase fulfilment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-events,

Comment: @PaulAsjes I am able to make payments. But what I want is to save the user info from front-end, probably an Stripe API. Moreover, I don't have sudo permission on server.